# Having 2 positions for the same li tag in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am to make a working login page via PHP but to also build a website front end for the user to be able to navigate around. For my navigation bar I want the bar to be static at the top and make it fixed (this bit I can do) but I also want some of the text to be at the top left hand-side of the nav bar (for general navigation) and 1 piece of text to be at the right-hand side (this is where the members will go to login in). I wish to make my CSS neat, and refrain from using multiple values (I.E font-family: "name";).

Here's the code and I'm hoping you can help:

```
.siteNavigation ul{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

.siteNavigation li{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    **text-align: left;**
 }

.siteNavigation a{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Armata";
}

#membersArea a{
    **text-align: right;**
```

I hope the CSS gives you some light on what I want, if not use the image:
[login example but with logo not text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMTmz.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for float on CSS.
You can add `float:right` and `float:left` to the classes you want to align on right and left.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help here! (I can't vote up because im a n00b)